# Oracle-Spring JDBCTemplate and ActiveMQ Artemis Embedded message grouping update mismatch

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

We are using embedded instance of ActiveMQ Artemis 2.28.0. with Spring Boot 3.0. Oracle version using is Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.

**Our requirement is to group the same Email Id to avoid concurrent update on the database.**
We have 15 producers that sends emailId count to 10 Consumers. Each consumer update database with below code

```
update T_BIL_MULTIPLE_INVOICES set SEND_EMAILCOUNT=SEND_EMAILCOUNT+1 where emailId=?
```

The same email ID can come from multiple producers that goes to different consumers and results in concurrent updates(We know Oracle internally handles but sometimes hang). Grouping can help to overcome these concurrent updates since the same email sent to the same consumer in sequential order.

**What we've done**

```java
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> connectionFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setConcurrency("1-10");
    factory.setErrorHandler(jmsErrorHandler);
    factory.setSubscriptionDurable(false);
    return factory;
}

public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    template.setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter());
    template.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
    template.setMessageIdEnabled(false);
    template.setMessageTimestampEnabled(false);
    return template;
}
    
public void sendInvoiceGroup(FileScannerDTO fileScannerDTO){
    if(fileScannerDTO.getMultipleInvoiceDTO() != null) {
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(emailGroupQueue, convertToInvoiceGroup(fileScannerDTO, fileScannerDTO.getMultipleInvoiceDTO()), message -> {
            message.setStringProperty("JMSXGroupID", fileScannerDTO.getEmailId());
            return message;
        });

@JmsListener(destination = "${dispatch.email.emailGroupQueue}",id ="receiverEmailGroupOne")
public void receiverEmailGroupOne(Map invoiceGroupDTO) {
    updateEmailGroup(invoiceGroupDTO);
}

public void updateEmailGroup(String emailId) throws SQLException {
        Log.info("EmailId----"+emailId)
        jdbcTemplate.update(InvoiceDispatchUtils.UPDATE_EMAILCOUNT_CONSUMER_STOPEMAIL, emailId);
}
```

In Addition Nine Listeners we have

***Our Issue After Grouping Implementation***

After grouping implementation Email count was not updating correctly. Even if the same emailId have multiple count in the queue its **updating only once if jdbcTemplate update is enabled**. Same emails are going through same consumers but update not happening correctly . This is working fine and printing email count correctly if we disable jdbcTemplate update. Some how queue is getting cleared after Oracle update transaction.

Working fine and count printed correctly **If jdbcTemplate is commented**. This confirms JMS grouping is fine and something related to Spring Transaction or Oracle Transaction that is making Artemis queue empty.

```java
public void updateEmailGroup(String emailId) throws SQLException {
        Log.info("EmailId----"+emailId)
        //jdbcTemplate.update(InvoiceDispatchUtils.UPDATE_EMAILCOUNT_CONSUMER_STOPEMAIL, emailId);
}
```